# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I encountered this error today, I search google for solution but I cannot find the correct answer for this. The error:

```
NoMethodError at /master/hotels/import

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the templete file:

```
row
.col-xs-12
%p.pull-left
  %button.btn.btn-white.btn-sm
    一括削除
%p.pull-right
  = link_to "新規作成",  url_for(action: :new), class: "btn btn-white btn-sm"
  = link_to "CSV Export", url_for(action: :index, format: 'csv'), class: "btn btn-white  btn-sm"
  = link_to "CSV Upload", url_for(action: :import), class: "btn btn-white btn-sm"
  -#= form_tag url_for(action: :import), class: 'pull-right' do |f|
    -#= file_field_tag :csv, as: :file
    -#= submit_tag "CSV Upload", input_html: {class: "btn btn-white btn-sm"}
 .col-xs-12
 = render 'cruds/grid'
```

and here is my controller file:

```
class CrudsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :load_crud
 before_action :set_crud, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def load_crud

 end

 # GET /cruds
 # GET /cruds.json
 def index
  @items_grid = initialize_grid(@model)

  @csv = CSV.generate() do |csv|
   csv << @model.column_names
   @model.all.each do |item|
     csv << item.attributes.values_at(*@model.column_names).map{|i|   i.to_s.encode("cp932", "UTF-8")}
   end
 end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render template: 'cruds/index'}
    format.csv { send_data @csv }
   #format.xls # {send_data @product.to_csv (col_sep: "|t")}
  end

  # render template: 'cruds/index'
end

# GET /cruds/1
# GET /cruds/1.json
def show
  render template: 'cruds/show'
end

# GET /cruds/new
 def new
  @crud = @model.new
  render template: 'cruds/new'
end

# GET /cruds/1/edit
def edit
  render template: 'cruds/edit'
end

# POST /cruds
# POST /cruds.json
def create
  @crud = @model.new(crud_params)

 respond_to do |format|
   if @crud.save
     format.html { redirect_to [:master, @crud], notice: 'Crud was successfully    created.' }
     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @crud }
   else
     format.html { render action: 'new' }
     format.json { render json: @crud.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

# PATCH/PUT /cruds/1
# PATCH/PUT /cruds/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
   if @crud.update(crud_params)
    format.html { redirect_to [:master, @crud], notice: 'Crud was successfully    updated.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   else
     format.html { render action: 'edit' }
     format.json { render json: @crud.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
 end

# DELETE /cruds/1
# DELETE /cruds/1.json
def destroy
 @crud.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to action: :index }
   format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end
def import
 @model.import(params[:file])
 redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
end


private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_crud
  @crud = @model.find_by_id(params[:id])
end

 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
 def crud_params
  params[@hash].permit(@model.attribute_names)
 end
```

end

I'm very confused about this error, can someone tell me any solution?

Comment: It would be great if you pasted the stacktrace along with the error. The cause is, something, somewhere, invoked the `id` method on a `nil`.

Comment: the screenshot error here: http://postimg.org/image/b2mwn3usp/ hope it help

Comment: Screenshots hosted outside of Stack Overflow are frowned upon, since they might expire and break the question. Also, it is easier to process text than images. And finally, it did not have the stack trace (even though it did have the code where the error occurs, so that was lucky).

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over attribute names of `@model`, and reading them on `@crud`. `@model` has an attribute named `id`; `@crud` is `nil`. Either both should be same (probably), or in the somewhat unusual case that you do mean to read `@model`'s attributes off of `@crud`, you need to check where `@crud` is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing, some small comments:

```
model.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Should be:

```
model.find(params[:id])
```

Next I would make sure that your view actually passes params[:id] to the view and not something like crud_id. If the latter is the case you should call this:

```
model.find_by(crud_id: params[:crud_id])
```

Lastly, I think you should add :file to your strong parameters.